# Dynamic root element with Jackson

Tags: java, xml, jackson, xml-serialization, jackson-dataformat-xml

I'm currently working on a project that deals with elements that (for legacy reasons) must have a tag name that represents their type.

Basically I have this:

```java
@JsonRootName("node")
class NodeDocument {
    private String type;
}
```

Which outputs something like:

```xml
<node type="someType"></node>
```

But what's expected would be:

```xml
<someType></someType>
```

`@JsonRootName` doesn't seem to be usable on a method or attribute.

Even though there is `SerializationConfig.withRooName()` or custom serializers, I can't seem to find a way to define the root name with a dynamic value stored in the object itself.

Comment: Take a look at this answer: [Multiple Jackson XML Custom (XMLStreamWriter) Serialisers throws Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57296440/51591). You need to implement custom serialiser and set root name from given instance using `ToXmlGenerator` class and `setNextName` method.

Comment: Thank you very much; I didn't know about `setNextName` but is there any facility to avoid all the boilerplate code necessary to serialize the object's attributes please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume `NodeDocument` contains more than just one property. In that case you need to implement custom serialiser together with `BeanSerializerModifier` which allow you to serialise all properties. Below code shows complete solution:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.BeanDescription;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonSerializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationConfig;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.module.SimpleModule;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializerModifier;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.util.NameTransformer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.ser.ToXmlGenerator;

import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Objects;

public class XmlJacksonApp {

    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
        SimpleModule dynamicRootNameModule = new SimpleModule();
        dynamicRootNameModule.setSerializerModifier(new DynamicRootNameBeanSerializerModifier());

        XmlMapper mapper = XmlMapper.xmlBuilder()
                .enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT)
                .addModule(dynamicRootNameModule)
                .build();
        NodeDocument element = new NodeDocument();
        element.setId(123);
        element.setName("Rick and Morty.doc");
        element.setType("sitcom");

        mapper.writeValue(System.out, element);
    }
}

class DynamicRootNameBeanSerializerModifier extends BeanSerializerModifier {
    @Override
    public JsonSerializer<?> modifySerializer(SerializationConfig config, BeanDescription beanDesc, JsonSerializer<?> serializer) {
        if (beanDesc.getBeanClass() == NodeDocument.class) {
            return new NodeDocumentJsonSerializer((JsonSerializer<NodeDocument>) serializer);
        }
        return super.modifySerializer(config, beanDesc, serializer);
    }
}

class NodeDocumentJsonSerializer extends JsonSerializer<NodeDocument> {
    private final JsonSerializer<NodeDocument> serializer;

    NodeDocumentJsonSerializer(JsonSerializer<NodeDocument> serializer) {
        this.serializer = Objects.requireNonNull(serializer);
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(NodeDocument value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {
        ToXmlGenerator xmlGen = (ToXmlGenerator) gen;
        writeDynamicRootName(value.getType(), xmlGen);
        serializeProperties(value, gen, serializers);
        writeEndObject(xmlGen);
    }

    private void writeDynamicRootName(String rootName, ToXmlGenerator xmlGen) throws IOException {
        xmlGen.setNextName(new QName("", rootName));
        xmlGen.writeStartObject();
    }

    private void serializeProperties(NodeDocument value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {
        serializer.unwrappingSerializer(NameTransformer.NOP).serialize(value, gen, serializers);
    }

    private void writeEndObject(ToXmlGenerator xmlGen) throws IOException {
        xmlGen.writeEndObject();
    }
}

class NodeDocument {

    @JsonIgnore
    private String type;
    private int id;
    private String name;

    // getters, setters
}
```

Above code prints:

```
<sitcom>
  <id>123</id>
  <name>Rick and Morty.doc</name>
</sitcom>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can easily switch/configure mapper a dirty and not so configurable but still quite easy way would be to override `XmlMapper` like:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class MyXmlMapper extends XmlMapper {
    @Override
    public String writeValueAsString(Object value) throws JsonProcessingException {
        String xml = super.writeValueAsString(value);
        if(value instanceof NodeDocument) {
            return xml.replaceAll("NodeDocument", ((NodeDocument)value).getType());
        }
        return xml;
    }
}
```

Not a perfect solution by any means and may not be suitable for all situations but as an example of one option as to be changed according to the situation.